# How to redirect /?page=1 to /page/1 using htccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to Redirect http://www.example.com/?page=1 to http://www.example.com/page/1 using Htaccess.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
`

Answer (score 0):

copy & paste this code in .htaccess file in your root directory

To keep the prefix and replace the last part with a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteRule ^root/pages/(.+)$ /root/pages/?id=$1 [L]
```

The RewriteCond is needed to prevent a rewrite loop.